# EditPad Regex replacement of transcription timestamps

Tags: regex, editpad

I am trying to take the transcription text from a Youtube video and parse it out into a document for editing.
I have been able to remove the majority of the HTML markup that is placed in it. However, I would like to remove the code below, which is the timestamp and offset that has already been parsed into  a single string.

I've tried this but I am no good at regexes:

`/^\d{2}\:\d{8}\"\>$/gm`

In Regex101 tester (https://regex101.com/r/a9wi2j/3/), it works but in EditPad replace, it does not.

What regex in EditPad would remove all the lines ending with below `">`?

```
03:17197850">
that so if you have production staff you
03:21201780">
can create logins like that for them and
03:24204299">
then they have access to all the
03:25205739">
information and everything they need but
03:27207359">
they can't go in and adjust pricing on
03:30210060">
```

Comment: Remove the backslash after `>`: `(?m)^\d{2}\:\d{8}\">$`

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: The original one you posted didn't but the new one did, post as answer, please.

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for, but in vim you could do `:g/">$/d`

Comment: the vim regex didn't work in Editpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove backslash before `>` because in earlier versions of EditPad `\>` had been interpreted as a word boundary and recent versions don't support this token.

You need to enable `m` flag too as you did in provided demo:

```
(?m)^\d{2}\:\d{8}\">$
```

Comment: `(?m)^\d*\:\d*\">$` actually works better because the seconds + offset may be more than 8 digits. I know the minutes is always 2 digits but using the * helps if the minutes goes over 99. I don't know how the time and offsets look for videos > 60 mins.